# Is it possible to use AWS lambda for routing traffic from ELB to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Current AWS configuration which is serving 3 webapps -

[image]

Here ELB is taking care of SSL offloading. Currently the Node JS application is deployed on a EC2 machine. It is taking care of handling the backend APIs as well as serving the static files for the 3 SPA react webapps.

We are looking to improve on this by separating out the frontend and backend. We are thinking of moving the 3 SPA react webapps into a single S3 bucket. Each will sit in its own directory on this S3 bucket. The S3 bucket will be configured for static website hosting. We will still have the node JS instance for service backend APIs.

[image]

We are looking to avoid using cloud front to route traffic from ELB to S3 since these are internal webapps with limited number of users from a particular region.

1. Can we use lambda function to route traffic from ELB to Node JS app on EC2 as well as from ELB to the S3 bucket? If possible is it a good practice performance wise and cost wise to take this approach?

Also the lambda function has to route the traffic based on rules -

- /api/* --> route traffic to node js app
- /ui/site1/* --> route traffic to S3 bucket site1 directory
- /ui/site2/* --> route traffic to S3 bucket site2 directory
- /ui/site3/* --> route traffic to S3 bucket site3 directory

  2. Can we write such rules in lambda function?

Comment: I would definitely use Cloudfront for this. Not only does it do what you want, but it will also reduce your S3 bandwidth costs.

Comment: You said you are looking to improve on this. What improvements are you specifically looking for? Simply offloading the delivery of static assets from your web server? Have you considered an HTTP cache such as varnish?

Comment: @jarmod I would not advise putting varnish in front of S3. That really defeats the purpose of S3 IMO.

Comment: @jordanm Agree, but I was referring to caching the HTTP content from the origin web server. The assets are not in S3 yet so a move to S3 is not a given at this point. Of course, S3/CloudFront would be the typical recommendation, but I'm offering an alternative given the desire to avoid CloudFront.

Comment: @jordanm will Cloudfront make my apps public? or can I still make it private? with cloudfront i would need to create seaparte disctributions for each of the webapps.

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya Yeah, cloudfront will make it public. One distribution can point to multiple origins, so you would only need one distribution

Comment: @jordanm having each of the sites in separate folders on one s3 bucket will cause deep linking issue. If the file is not found on s3 bucket, the response should be index.html of the corresponding site. This setting cannot be done on cloud front. also exposing the internal sites to public would not be recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can implement a Lambda that retrieves content from S3. You simply need to extract the request path from the invocation event, translate that to whatever S3 location you're using, retrieve the file, and package it in the response.

**BUT**

You're limited to 1MB response data, so if you have any images or other large files, you won't be able to serve them ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html)).

And you'll be paying Lambda invocation costs for every file that you retrieve, which is admittedly small.

And you'll be increasing the time to retrieve each file, which will slow down your web-app. How much depends on how many static assets you're loading.

A better solution, if you want to split static and dynamic content and don't want to use CloudFront, would be to spin up another Node.JS server on a different port, and have the ALB point at it.

Comment: the only reason i dont want to use cloud front is that I will have to create separate distributions for each of the sites with the routing rules for these distributions handled at the ELB. Also these are internal private sites. There is no need to make them public. Not sure whether I can make the sites private when using cloud front.

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya - so use my recommended solution and spin up another Node instance on the same EC2 instance, to serve static content.

Comment: each of these sites are micro apps. there will be frequent addition of new micro apps. Each time there is a new app, someone has to make changes in the node code. Would like to avoid this overhead.

Comment: each of these sites are micro apps. there will be frequent addition of new micro apps. Each time there is a new app, someone has to make changes in the node code. Would like to avoid this overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Application load balancers already support [path based routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html). But won't support the S3 bucket as a valid target, so you'd want a Lambda for that to echo the contents.

So

- /api/* --> target group with the NodeJS app running behind it
- /ui/site* --> lambda, echoing the contents of the S3 object

Comment: can you direct me to the nodejs lambda code to echo the s3 contents?